# Write UTF-8 JSON file from PHP code in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that needs to be able to write and read complex data encoded as JSON which can contain UTF-8 encoded text. I've had problems reading the file (I get PHP parse errors), but I now suspect that this is because the data is not actually encoded as UTF-8 (as I expected) but as HTML-encoded entities.

The functions that open the output buffer and write into it look like this -- am I missing something??

```
public function createUTFOutput($filename, $json)
{
        // Tells the browser to expect a json file and bring up the save dialog in the browser
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);

    if ($json)
        header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    else
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

        // This opens up the output buffer as a "file"
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // Hack to write as UTF-8 format
    fwrite($fp, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
    return $fp;
} // createUTFOutput()

    // PURPOSE: Write out data about Attribute $the_att to file $fp
public function write_att_data($fp, $the_att)
{
        // Create header to indicate Attribute record
    fwrite($fp, '{"type": "Attribute", "att-id": "'.$the_att->id.'", '."\n");
    fwrite($fp, '"att-privacy": "'.$the_att->privacy."\", \n");
    fwrite($fp, '"att-def": '.$the_att->meta_def.", \n");
    fwrite($fp, '"att-range": '.$the_att->meta_range.", \n");
    fwrite($fp, '"att-legend": '.$the_att->meta_legend."\n}");
} // write_att_data()
```

Is some other setting necessary so that the text is written as UTF-8 characters for a file, rather than as HTML encoded characters as though it were being displayed on a screen? Could it alternatively be that it is the input process that is somehow converting UTF-8 characters into HTML-encoded characters? When I look at the MIME-type of the files stored on my Mac, they do look correct.

Comment: Since you are using WordPress, why are you trying to do things in a unique way (writing configuration to a file and encoding in in JSON) when there is ample support for configuration options in WordPress built-in and easily managable?

Comment: It's nothing to do with configuring WordPress -- the plugin is a complex application in itself and I need to be able to export and import data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing the same issues, there are major complications because of unpredictable and silent conversions of encodings, etc.  But this blog entry is very helpful to me: https://www.stefan-wallin.se/utf-8-issues-in-wordpress-with-update_post_meta-and-json_encode/

Answer (score 0):

Never write your own serialization function.  Your code will inevitably generate invalid JSON.

JSON, by specification, is UTF-8.  I'd imagine if you simply used PHP's built-in `json_encode()`, everything would be fine.

Your encoded entity problem is due to WordPress's built-in functionality.  I don't know how to override it off the top of my head, but it's been done before.

Comment: Why would my code “inevitably generate invalid JSON”? It produces good JSON files -- the only problem is with non-ASCII characters.  The text that is being copied is either strings, or else text that is the result of json_encode().

Comment: @user3780094 "the only problem is with non-ASCII characters", for starters, that's one issue.  Also, you're not escaping anything in the output.  If you're encoding it elsewhere that's probably not a huge problem but there's definitely no need to do what you're doing when there are built-in methods that are guaranteed to work.

Comment: What built-in methods? I need to save and load data files that have encoded JSON. It's not helpful to question the requirements of the system, or the fact that WordPress simply does not supply the functionality that this application needs. If you can offer specific solutions to this very specific code I've provided, that would be very useful to me and probably others.

Answer (score -3):

The utf8_encode() function might help.

Comment: That's not very specific. Isn't text in WordPress already encoded as UTF-8? Why do I need to encode it again?

Comment: I suggested it because I ran into a similar problem while creating a function to take a JSON object and dump it into an array. It crapped out on some characters so I had to use utf8_encode() as a middleman between.

Comment: @belinus: I see this type of answer around often, but most of the time it's a bad idea to just blindly apply this function. The function doesn't converts *anything* to utf-8, but rather it only converts latin-1 to utf-8. Step one is always to fully figure out the source encoding, only then you pick the appropriate conversion method.